# Magento2 inventory_cleanup_reservations CRON job not working as expected for the large number of reservation records

Tags: magento2, inventory, cataloginventory

The basic reason behind this is the MySQL group_concat_max_len value. If we have a large number of records in the reservation table then it fails to group concat the value.

**Preconditions and environment**
Magento 2.4.4 (enterprise) Actually for any version

**Steps to reproduce**

- Three Order should be placed
- The first two orders can have a single product but the third order should have more than one product.
- Create a shipment for all the orders and observe the inventory_reservation table.
  [image]
- To verify the issue with a small amount of data please modify the value of the groupConcatMaxLen variable from file vendor/magento/module-inventory-reservations/etc/di.xml. The default value is 32768 but for testing purposes, I have changed that to 3.
  [image]
- Now to the setup:di: compile & flush the cache
- Now manually execute the inventory_cleanup_reservations cron or wait for the cron to execute. Observe the inventory_reservation table.
  [image]
- As per the above screenshot, the shipment_created reservation has not been deleted for the order #000000003. which should be deleted because compensation has happened for the order #000000003.
- Now if you execute the inventory_cleanup_reservations cron as many as times you want it will not delete the records for order #000000003. It is because it didn't find the compensation for the order placed
- Now check the salable qty on the product grid. The salable qty is more than the source qty
  [image]

**Expected result**
The reservation should be deleted for all the compensated orders and the product salable qty should be corrected

**Actual result**
The reservation has not been deleted for all the compensated orders.